# what does "they" refer in a paragraph

Tags: pronouns

> Sometimes  dreams  are  terrifying,  but  **they**  are  usually  a  collection  of  scattered,  confused thoughts.  If  you  dream  about  something  that  is  worrying  you,  you  may  wake  up  exhausted  sweating, and  with  a  rapid  heartbeat.  Dreams  have  positive  effects  on  our  lives.

In this paragraph, what does "they" refer to?  In my opinion,  as a pronoun rule, it refers to "dreams". But ,in the sense of context, it could refer to "terrifying dreams". Please share your opinions with me.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question . .. No, nobody would take *they* to refer to *terrifying dreams*, for two reasons:

1. There is no noun phrase  *terrifying dreams* present for *they* to refer to. A predication, *X is Y*, is quite different from a noun phrase *Y X*.
2. *But* entails a contrast between the two clauses it joins. In this case, *sometimes* and *usually* provide the terms which distinguish the contrasting elements:

   ```
    Sometimes dreams    are terrifying
   ```

   but usually    they     are a collection

   We are talking about *dreams* as they appear on different occasions; the second first clause describes dreams as they *sometimes* appear, which is different than they appear *usually*.